# Create a function with slashes and backslashes

Tags: javascript

I have to create a line on two with slashes and backslashes. I am obligated to use several functions in this exercise.

Here is an example:

```
///////////
\\\\\\\\\\\
///////////
\\\\\\\\\\\
///////////
\\\\\\\\\\\
```

My problem is that, I get an error message **"undefined"** on each line.

```
///////////
undefined
\\\\\\\\\\\
undefined
///////////
undefined
\\\\\\\\\\\
undefined
///////////
undefined
\\\\\\\\\\\
```

I don't understand where is the problem?

```
displayLine();

function slash(){
    var slash = "";
    for(var i=0; i<11; i++){
        slash += "/";
    }
    console.log(slash);
}

function antiSlash(){
    var antiSlash = "";
    for(var i=0; i<11; i++){
        antiSlash += "\\";
    }
    console.log(antiSlash);
}

function displayLine(){
    for(var i=0; i<6; i++){
        if(i % 2 === 0){
            console.log(slash());
        } else {
            console.log(antiSlash());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `console.log` in partial functions (`slash()` and `antiSlash()`) to `return`.

```
displayLine();

function slash(){
    var slash = "";
    for(var i=0; i<11; i++){
        slash += "/";
    }
    return slash;
}

function antiSlash(){
    var antiSlash = "";
    for(var i=0; i<11; i++){
        antiSlash += "\\";
    }
    return antiSlash;
}

function displayLine(){
    for(var i=0; i<6; i++){
        if(i % 2 === 0){
            console.log(slash());
        } else {
            console.log(antiSlash());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `slash` and `antiSlash` don't return anything.  You have to decide, is `slash` going to return a string that the caller prints, or is `slash` going to do the printing and the caller does nothing?  Only one of the two needs to call `console.log`.

Answer (score 1):

`slash` and `antislash` don't return anything, but you're trying to log what they return. Remove the `console.log`s wrapping the calls in `displayLine`, that's what's outputting `undefined`.

Alternatively, leave them in, and change the functions being called to `return` the constructed string instead of `log`ing it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a better way, definitely shorter

```js
console.log(
  Array.from(Array(6).keys()).map(v => (v % 2 === 0 ? '/' : '\\').repeat(11)).join('\n')
)
```

> I am obligated to use several functions in this exercise.

```js
const a = v => v.join('\n')
const c = v => Array.from(Array(v).keys())
const b = v => v.map(v => (v % 2 === 0 ? '/' : '\\').repeat(11))
console.log(
  a(b(c(6)))
)
```